# How to select text then convert with html tag?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

LIke

```
This is a paragraph.
```

IF i select this text then press any keypoard shortcut.

it should be chnage to this

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

I need auto hot key script and will add more tag. i need a editable script for `<p`> then i will add for other tag as per requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a similar approach that I used in your other question, use the clipboard buffer:

```
!p::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Send ^c
clipwait
Clipboard = <p>%Clipboard%</p>
Send ^v
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved=
return
```

give it a test run for me!

Comment: +1: An answer more than four years old and still helpful to me today.