# if selected text has site url and email address then i want to convert all url and email address into link?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

for example

**this**

None of the shortcuts are things you couldn't do within Windows with a few extra clicks or with a small 3rd-party app, but **http://JDContextMenu.com** bundles them together into a small menu with one-click ease. You can copy the full **email@filename.com** to the clipboard

**Should be converted into this**

```
None of the shortcuts are things you couldn't do within Windows with a few extra clicks or with a small 3rd-party app, but <a href="http://JDContextMenu.com" title="Opens in a new window" target="_blank">http://JDContextMenu.com</a> bundles them together into a small menu with one-click ease. You can copy the full <a href="mailto:email@filename.com">email@filename.com</a> to the clipboard
```

And i want to combine this facility with this script [How to select text then convert with html tag?](https://superuser.com/questions/98092/how-to-select-text-then-convert-with-html-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AutoHotkey script should work, identifying both URLs and email addresses.

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is the hotkey defined:

```
!p::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Clipboard=
Send ^c
ClipWait, 2
clipcontent = %Clipboard%
; Regular Expressions from RegExLib.com
; First lets search for the URLs
clipcontent := RegExReplace(clipcontent, "Si)(((file|gopher|news|nntp|telnet|http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://)|(www\.))+(([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(/[a-zA-Z0-9\&amp;%_\./-~-]*)?", "<a href=""$0"">$0</a>")
; And then for the email addresses
clipcontent := RegExReplace(clipcontent, "Si)[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(aero|coop|info|museum|name))", "<a href=""mailto:$0"">$0</a>")
Clipboard = <p>%clipcontent%</p>
ClipWait, 2
Send ^v
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipWait, 2
ClipSaved=
return
```

Comment: thanks, combine ut this script with this http://superuser.com/questions/98092/how-to-select-text-then-convert-with-html-tag

Comment: Already done by the line `Clipboard = <p>%clipcontent%</p>`

Comment: cool, pls can u make this possible also http://superuser.com/questions/100870/how-to-select-text-and-convert-any-charcter-into-html-entity-which-should-be-i-n